# What is the point of a vacuum pump with a fuel injection engine?

Tags: obd-ii

I recently got an [OBD-II dongle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0076KBPNI) with the Torque Android app, which allows me to read the computer's output in real time. The app will let me drag and drop different gauges on my screen, which works out great. However, there is a gauge for vacuum pump pressure, and I don't know why the vehicle (2008 Tundra) would have one.

**So, what is the function of a vacuum pump in a modern engine, or is this just a label problem with the app?**

Comment: Does said gauge actually give you any readings?

Comment: @hillsons Yes, it did give actual readings.. not sure of what range though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diesel engines typically have a vacuum pump to supply power to the brake boosters. If your 2008 Tundra doesn't have a diesel engine, then that gauge is likely referring to the vacuum pressure being measured in your intake manifold.

Comment: Also turbo or supercharged engines

Answer (score 1):

The OBD-II protocol is standard across all engine types post-1999( or thereabout). That means Torque will allow you to read all the standard outputs, even if your car doesn't happen to have that particular device. You'll just get a gauge that doesn't actually do anything.

By the way, I've had Torque for just over a year and it's fantastic.